# How to toggle between animation states with Unity Mecanim

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Hey I've been having a problem with switching between animation states for unity.
I currently have it set so that it transitions to crouch when the bool parameter "Crouching" is true and back to standing when "Crouching" is false. I would like this to be toggled with the c key and though I can get the animator to crouch, I can`t go back with it.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
        Anim.SetBool ("Crouching", true);
        Anim.SetFloat ("vertical", CForwardAnim);
        Anim.SetFloat ("horizontal", CSidewaysAnim);
```

This is what I have so far, sorry if it isn't in great form, I'm rather new to all of this and am picking it up as I go.

Comment: What about `(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C))`  When you release C. Make your bool false.

Comment: I think that would work, but unfortunately I want it to be able to crouch when c is pressed, then stand up when c is pressed again.

Comment: Add a bool like isCrouching. Make it false at the beginning. When pressed c make this other of its state. Like toggle you said. `isCrouching = !isCrouching`. Something like this might help.